# Select a range of records in Informix on AIX

Tags: sql, informix

I am trying to select records in chunks of 10K using the query below:

select first 10000 *  from  where ='999'

How do I select the next few groups of records.

Any help in this regard is appreciated. Informix is not allowing the use of Limit or Fetch.

Answer (score 1):

No worries I got the answer:

```
select skip 10000 first 10000
       *  -- or whatever columns are needed
  from table A, table B
 where a.cola = b.cola
```

This will select the rows 10001 to 20000.

The query below selects rows 20001 to 30000

```
select skip 20000 first 10000
       *  -- or whatever columns are needed
  from table A, table B
 where a.cola=b.cola
```

And so on....to select rows 30001-40000

```
select skip 30000 first 10000
       * -- or whatever columns are needed
  from table A, table B
 where a.cola = b.cola
```

Comment: The Informix manual for the [projection list](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0156.htm) in a SELECT statement affirms this. AFAIK, in a programming language, you can use a placeholder (`?`) for the skip and first values, so that you can reuse a single prepared statement to collect all the data: `SELECT SKIP ? FIRST ? * FROM table AS A JOIN table AS B ON A.ColA = B.ColA`.